# Have buttons override other processes

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, viewdidappear

In my app, the root view controller acquires information from the internet, parses it, and displays it in `viewDidAppear`.  I am using this method because my app in embedded in a `UINavigationController` and this way the root view controller will reload its data when the user presses the back button and pops to the root view.

When this occurs, it takes some time for the information from the internet to be acquired and displayed.  During this time, if the user clicks a button to move to a different view, the button action will not occur until the view controller has completed its process of acquiring the web data.

How can I make it so that the buttons will override the other processes and immediately switch the view?  Is this safe?  Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Here's an example of a portion where I take the information off of the site (My app parses the HTML).

```
NSURL *siteURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ridgefield.org/ajax/dist/emergency-announcements"];
NSError *error;
NSString *source = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:siteURL 
                                            encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                               error:&error];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where Apple folks would hound, "don't block the main thread!".

The primary suggestion for this kind of workflow is to use a separate thread (read: queue) for loading data from the web. Then the worker who completes the load can set some property on your view controller, and inside that setter is where the UI should be updated. Remember to call the setter back on the main thread.

There are several ways to skin the concurrency cat, but the answer to this particular question leaves them out of scope. The short answer is to not do the load in the main thread, and that should lead you to the right place.

Comment: I've looked into threads, but Apple doesn't seem to want you to perform anything to do with the web on secondary threads?

Comment: I've not seen any sentiments like this in the documentation. I have two very web-heavy apps, and 100% of our loads happen in alternative threads. Sometimes using NSOperationQueue to spawn many threads in parallel which are each loading from the web. There is an answer below suggesting an 'off the shelf' technique for loading in another thread, but it's essentially the same answer as this.

Comment: So would I be able to perform the code in my question, through another thread?

Comment: Yes. The short answer is to wrap that into a block that also has a weak reference to the caller view controller and dispatch it to another queue. There are many SO questions and much good documentation on that. It's about a 30-60 minute learning curve, but knowing how to quickly leverage Grand Central Dispatch will be well worth your time. Just keep in mind to call back to the VC on the main queue (`dispatch_get_main_queue()`)

Comment: So if have this thread run, and then the user clicks a button to switch the view controller, will the thread just stop with no harm?

Comment: It won't stop by itself, no. But you have options when you want them. At first if you use a synchronous call, it will not get cancelled at all, but when it calls the callback, you can (inside the callback) check if you are onscreen and not update UI if not. In the future if you want better ability to stop the load in the middle, you will need to use a more complex technique for loading, implementing the URLConnection delegate methods and in each of them checking if your callback VC is onscreen, canceling the load if not. This is getting out of scope for this question, but it's the right path.

Answer (score 1):

The NSString method stringWithContentsOfURL is synchronous and will block your main thread.

Instead of using background threads to solve the problem, you can use asynchronous URL requests.  This does not block the user interface because a delegate protocol is used to let you know when the request is complete.  For example:

```
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@""http://www.ridgefield.org/ajax/dist/emergency-announcements""];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        NSURLConnection* theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

And then some of your delegate methods are:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)theResponse
{
    // create received data array
    _receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init]; 
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)theData
{
    // append to received data.
    [_receivedData appendData:theData];
}


-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection
{
    // now the connection is complete
    NSString* strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: _receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // now parse strResult
}
```

Comment: This technique still uses another thread, you just don't directly manage it.

Comment: In addition, you need to manage several additional delegate methods to collect the data being loaded, adding to the complexity. It can be much simpler to plop a block on another queue which does a synchronous load (similar to the code just added to the question)

Comment: OK, but the problem to be solved here is that the UI is blocked.

Comment: So would I be able to perform the code in my question, using this method?

Comment: Well, are you doing a GET on webpage, or some other type of communication?

Comment: I'm just performing the above code to get the HTML source.  Then I'm parsing it.  I'm asking you this because, although your method looks very good, it might not be a good fit for what I'm doing.

Comment: Yes, if you are reading a webpage, this method will work, and it won't block your user interface.